# Reading and storing a stream of UDP datagrams in c++ 98 and berkeley sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, streaming

**Setup**: This is a dynamic library made only for openSUSE linux, using C++ 98 due to strict requirements, and Berkeley Sockets. I have a stream of UDP datagrams sent at 90hz from another pc.
I'm following the great [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/) for this.

**Intented behaviour:** I'm providing a dinamic library as the interface with the network and it should store the latest datagram received so that when you ask for it, it will be returned.

**Options**

- Option A) PASSIVE LIBRARY: Make them call an Update() method at those 90Hz (more or less) to make it read the datagrams from the socket and get the latest one. If not called frequently enough it will not work well.
- Option B) ACTIVE LIBRARY: make the library perform the check itself at 90Hz (more or less). I guess I would need to use a thread for this, am I right?. I have no idea how to make it sleep so that it doesn't waste CPU and resources. No idea how to do this.

**Problem**: I created two little apps, one sends the datagrams at 90hz, another reads them. Active wait works, but as soon as I introduce a while loop reading the socket all the time, it returns no datagrams. The socket is always empty. I've been told to use "Select()" with a timeout. But I guess both do something similar. Why isn't there anything in the socket when I do this?

```
for(;;)
{
    numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXBUFLEN-1 , 0, p->ai_addr, &p->ai_addrlen);

    if (numbytes == 0)
    {
        printf("Error. Sender closed connection?\n");
        break;
    }
    else if (numbytes > 0)
    {
        printf("listener: got packet from %s\n",inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr(p->ai_addr), s, sizeof s));
        printf("listener: packet is %d bytes long\n", numbytes);
        buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("listener: packet contains \"%s\"\n", buf);
    }
}
```

**Questions**

- Are the datagrams lost if I don't wait actively for them?
- In case they are stored, why aren't they available when I fetch them with the while loop?
- In case they are stored, how many are stored?
- Is there any way to make the socket store the latest package by itself and letting me fetch the last one?

Comment: One question per stackoverflow.com question, please. TLDR: you have no guarantees, whatsoever, with UDP datagrams.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, I know. Sorry about that. All of them are relatated. Storing or not, how many, socket buffer, and why it doesn't work. I removed the rest of the stuff

Comment: FYI, UDP datagrams can have 0-byte payloads. There is no connection in UDP, so `recvfrom()` will not return 0 when the "Sender closed connection", only when a 0-byte datagram is received (since you are using a non-zero buffer). `recvfrom()` will return < 0 on failure (check `errno` for why it failed), or >= 0 on success. Also, you don't need to null-terminate the buffer to use `printf()`, you can pass the byte count to `printf()` as a parameter, eg: `printf("listener: packet contains \"%.*s\"\n", numbytes, buf);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Awesome tips! Thanks.   I noticed that after testing for a while.